# python 2.7.3 already installed(but no pysqlite). how to add it to my virtualenv?

Tags: python

I already installed python 2.7.3 into a directory and created virtualenvs using this python . Now, when I tried to run ipython, it said it needs sqlite for saving history. So i tried installing using pip install pysqlite, but it is returning errors.

src/module.c: In function ‘init_sqlite’:

src/module.c:426: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sqlite3_libversion’

src/module.c:426: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘PyString_FromString’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: How did you install IPython?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the development version of sqlite3 on your system. What's your system/OS, and how did you install python 2.7?

Comment: ubuntu ..i had some old version of python in /usr/bin. So, followed some method from stackoverflow question and downloaded python2.7 source and installed into a custom folder. Then, while creating virtualenv, added some attribute which tells what python(path) to use for the venv.